# How to implement a timer which automatically sets the JTextArea to the next line after 5 seconds?

Tags: java, timer

I am creating a basic Java Visual Novel of sorts. It reads a text file and each line in the file is inserted into an ArrayList. By pressing the previous and next buttons, it changes the JTextArea into the next line or previous line.

Now, I want to use a timer so that it does the prev-next thing automatically. How do I go about doing that?
Here is my code:

```
public class FormativeAss1 {
URL ahaha = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ahaha.wav");
URL horror = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("horror.wav");
URL clash = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("clash.wav");
URL goriri = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("goriri.wav");
URL impact = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("impact.wav");
URL hakushu = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hakushu.wav");

JTextArea dialogue_label;
int secondsToWait = 5;
JButton nextButton, prevButton;
Timer tm;
private JFrame frame;
int IntegerQueue = -1;
JLabel Background;
int startedchecker = 0;


public void playSound(URL soundFile) {
    try {
      AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
      clip.open(audioInputStream);
      clip.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 

public void IntegerQueueSound(int integer) {
    switch (integer){
    case 0:
        playSound(clash);
        break;
    case 1:
        playSound(horror);
        break;
        
    case 2: 
        playSound(ahaha);
        break;
    case 3: 
        playSound(impact);
        break;
    case 4: 
        playSound(hakushu);
        break;
    case 5: 
        playSound(goriri);
        break;
    case 6: 
        playSound(ahaha);
        break;
    }
}


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FormativeAss1 window = new FormativeAss1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public  FormativeAss1() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 944, 595);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setFocusable(true);                          
    frame.getContentPane().requestFocusInWindow();
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("DesktopIcon.border"));
    panel.setBounds(10, 309, 908, 236);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    dialogue_label = new JTextArea("Press \"Start Dialogue\" to start the novel.");
    dialogue_label.setLineWrap(true);
    dialogue_label.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    dialogue_label.setColumns(1);
    dialogue_label.setRows(4);
    dialogue_label.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    dialogue_label.setBounds(10, 11, 888, 214);
    panel.add(dialogue_label);


    JButton StartDialogueButton = new JButton("Start Dialogue");
    StartDialogueButton.setBounds(10, 276, 142, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(StartDialogueButton);
    
    prevButton = new JButton("Previous");
    prevButton.setBounds(162, 276, 85, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(prevButton);
    
    nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    
    nextButton.setBounds(257, 276, 85, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(nextButton);
    
    JLabel Background = new JLabel("New label");
    Background.setBounds(-381, -72, 1257, 1000);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Background);
      String strLine = "";
        ArrayList < String > dialogue_List = new ArrayList < String > ();
        ArrayList < String > scenery_List = new ArrayList < String > (Arrays.asList("images/bea.png",
                "images/lam.png","images/but.png","images/enj.png","images/ros.png","images/eva.png"
                ,"images/ber.png", "images/kir.png"));
        
        try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Miko\\eclipse-workspace\\Fourth Quarter\\src\\FourthQuarter\\Script.txt"));
          while (strLine != null) {
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine == null) {
              break;
            
          }
        dialogue_List.add(strLine);}
          br.close();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
        }


        ListIterator<String> it = dialogue_List.listIterator();
    frame.getContentPane().setFocusable(true);                          
        frame.getContentPane().requestFocusInWindow();


            frame.getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(startedchecker==1){
                        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                        if(keyCode == 37) {
                                IntegerQueue = IntegerQueue - 1;
                                if(IntegerQueue < 0) {
                                    IntegerQueue = 0;
                                }
                        } else if(keyCode == 39) {
                            if (it.hasNext()) {
                            IntegerQueue = IntegerQueue + 1;}
                                dialogue_label.setText(dialogue_List.get(IntegerQueue));
                                Background.setIcon(new ImageIcon (scenery_List.get(IntegerQueue)));
                            IntegerQueueSound(IntegerQueue);

                        }
                    
                    }
                    
                    }
                });


    StartDialogueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        //depending on the IntegerQueue number, certain music or backgrounds will play at different intervals.
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               
             startedchecker=1;
            


                
                }
        
    });
    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(startedchecker==1) {
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                IntegerQueue = IntegerQueue + 1;
                dialogue_label.setText(dialogue_List.get(IntegerQueue));
                
                
                //IntegerQueue = IntegerQueue - 1;
                System.out.println(IntegerQueue);
                Background.setIcon(new ImageIcon (scenery_List.get(IntegerQueue)));
            IntegerQueueSound(IntegerQueue);
            }
        }
            }
    });
    
    
    prevButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg1) {
            if(startedchecker==1&&IntegerQueue>0) {
                
                IntegerQueue = IntegerQueue - 1;
                
            dialogue_label.setText(dialogue_List.get(IntegerQueue));
            
            
            
            System.out.println(IntegerQueue);
            Background.setIcon(new ImageIcon (scenery_List.get(IntegerQueue)));
            IntegerQueueSound(IntegerQueue);
            
            }
        }
    });
    
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
if(keyCode == 37) {

...

} else if(keyCode == 39) {
```

Don't use "magic numbers". We don't know what a key code of 37 or 39 is. Instead use variable provided by the KeyEvent class like KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN. This makes the code self documenting so we know what keys you are listening for.

> I want to use a timer so that it does the prev-next thing automatically

You need to refactor your code.

Your "next" and "previous" listeners need to be refactored into an `Action`. An `Action` is essentially the same as your ActionListener since it just implements the `actionPerformed(...)` method.

The benefit of the `Action` is that is can now be used by your JButton and by the Swing Timer and by using Key Bindings (which will replace your KeyListener).

Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The following sections will help you solve your problem:

1. `How to Use Actions`
2. `How to Use Key Bindings`
3. `How to Use Swing Timers`